# highchart line chart last null value is not conected with line

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am creating a highchart with series type line, the data having some null value as a last point. 
In this case. the line series is not connecting to the last point.

Any workaround is appreciated

```
series: [{
    data: [29.9, null, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, null, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, null],
    connectNulls: true
}]
```

I have provided the fiddle version also here http://jsfiddle.net/kalidoss_mca/xynZT/249/

Comment: Because the last point is `null` so there is nothing for line to connect to. This is standard `Highcharts` behavior.

Comment: @kalidoss connect it to what? Where do you want the line to go? connectNulls connect two points that have a null point in between them. It can't create imaginary points to connect to.

Comment: I wanted to connect to zero or yaxis min value if the first or last point is null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is working.
If the point has `null` value, it can't be represented in the chart.
`connectNulls: true` is used to avoid line breaking.

Look at [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/3frbe99u/1/).

Comment: is there any workaround available to connect the last point(null)

Comment: You can't represent a null value in the chart. It has no value.

Comment: As a workaround you can update your last point if its y value is equal to null: http://jsfiddle.net/xynZT/254/